# Perl DBI: Insert a whole hash in a single call, complement to fetchall_hashref()

Tags: perl, insert, dbi, hashref

I am using Perl DBI with DBD::Informix but I suspect the exact database is not important to this question.  Bottom line: I'm looking for a mass-insert method where I can insert the contents of a hash [of hashes] into a table in one call.

Commentary:

I have grown enamored of the Perl DBI method `fetchall_hashref()`, wherein I can run the query and fetch the whole blessed active set - which may be thousands of rows - into a hash in one call.

I'm reading through the POD on both of these modules, looking for some equivalent of this in an insert statement or PUT call, something like a putall_hashref() method.  The best I find is a simple one-row insert, where I've PREPAREd an INSERT statement with ? placeholders and then execute the PREPAREd stament.  I've used a PUT cursor available in ESQL/C (and Informix-4GL) but even those are still one row at time.

I need a mass-insert method.

### Is such a method in there someplace but I've missed it?

I see the comments by Shawn and zdim.

Shawn & zdim,

Example of current (untested) code, though I've used similar stuff before:

```
$db_partns = $extract_smi_p->fetchall_hashref("partition");
# Pulls from temp tab in DB1
```

...

## Now loop to insert each row from above hash into new temp table in another DB

```
for my $partn (keys %$db_partns)
{
  $put_statement_p->execute(@{$db_partns->{$partn}}{@partn_fields});
}
```

Note: @partn_fields is an array of keys i.e. column names.  (Using hash-slice scheme.)

To use execute_array() I'd need to separate all values in each column into a separate array.  Thanks for the clever idea; I may use it some day.  But to set that up is an even uglier setup than I'm already doing.

Comment: Show example of data and how you insert it now.  The insert statement takes multiple rows, but we'd need to see what you have and want with it.

Comment: I think `execute_array()` is the closest available. Or `execute_for_fetch()`.